# BIGQUERY ON BITCOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bitcoin

i use this code for get address with balance but i want to add count of address  transactions  to result .
can u help me

*

```
-- SQL source from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them
WITH double_entry_book AS (
   -- debits
   SELECT
    array_to_string(inputs.addresses, ",") as address
   , inputs.type
   , -inputs.value as value
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.inputs` as inputs
   UNION ALL
   -- credits
   SELECT
    array_to_string(outputs.addresses, ",") as address
   , outputs.type
   , outputs.value as value
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.outputs` as outputs
)
SELECT
   address
,   type   
,   sum(value) as balance
FROM double_entry_book
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY balance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

I am not all that familiar with the dataset but if each single output and input is classed as a single transaction then the number of transactions per address would just be the number of the rows there are for that address right? So you could add count(address) to count the transactions like this:

```
-- SQL source from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them
WITH double_entry_book AS (
   -- debits
   SELECT
    array_to_string(inputs.addresses, ",") as address
   , inputs.type
   , -inputs.value as value
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.inputs` as inputs
   UNION ALL
   -- credits
   SELECT
    array_to_string(outputs.addresses, ",") as address
   , outputs.type
   , outputs.value as value
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.outputs` as outputs
)
SELECT
   address
,   type   
,   sum(value) as balance
,   count(address) as transactions
FROM double_entry_book
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY balance DESC
LIMIT 100
```